# How to draw a undirected weighted graph on a Swing component?

Tags: java, swing, graph, graph-theory, jgrapht

I have this STP file that contains the undirected weighted graph information, this is a sample.

```
33D32945 STP File, STP Format Version 1.0

SECTION Comment
Name    "lin01"
Creator "C. Lin"
END

SECTION Graph
Nodes 53
Edges 80
E 1 32 46
E 1 25 26
E 2 51 10
E 2 32 74
E 2 11 70
E 42 50 2
E 43 53 42
E 47 53 46
END

SECTION Terminals
Terminals 4
T 1  
T 9
T 40
T 47
END

SECTION Coordinates
DD 1 420 128
DD 2 346 174
DD 3 0 0
DD 50 492 102
DD 51 346 184
DD 52 0 110
DD 53 346 102
END

EOF
```

I did not find anything about graphs in Netbeans so how to represent this undirected weighted graph in a `JFrame`. Could anyone provide me with examples and other resources?

Comment: You draw on a drawing `JPanel`, not a `JFrame`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) sections.

Comment: You can also look into Netbeans Visual library.  https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorials/60/nbm-visual_library.html